# Nginx: Automatic sub-domain creation if a folder exists

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, directory, subdirectory

I have this folder: /home/sites/dev/
Nginx serves the content of this folder if I visit "domain.com"

But, let's say that if I create a folder inside this folder, for example "wp-test", I want nginx to serve this folder if I visit "wp-test.domain.com"

It seems like "ianc" made it work on his [blog post](http://www.messaliberty.com/2010/10/automatic-nginx-virtual-subdomains-with-sub-folders-or-sub-directories/), but I can't get it to work.

Here's my config so far for nginx:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.ilundev.no;
    root /home/sites/dev;
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name   ~^(.*)\.ilundev\.no$;

    if (!-d /home/sites/dev/ilundev.no/public/$1) {
        rewrite . http://www.ilundev.no/ redirect;
    }

    root /home/sites/dev/$1;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ilundev.no;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.ilundev.no/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Does it redirect when the directory doesn't exist?

Comment: Nope, I always get "Server not found" whenever I type in something random or the correct name of the folder.

Comment: I get a DNS lookup error when I try to hit asdf.ilundev.no.  Perhaps this is a GitLab issue?

Comment: I have GitLab installed on the server the domain points to... But how did you figure out that? :D

Testing disablind the GitLab nginx block...

Comment: Just removed the gitlab entry in sites-enabled, and restarted Nginx. No dice :(

Comment: Found the GitLab thing by browsing the IP instead of the DNS name.

Comment: Guessing your DNS Zone is the culprit; need to set it up with the appropriate wildcards, but I have no expertise in that area.

Comment: Cheers for the help @adamdc78, it was really helpful and guided me in the right direction to solve it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work!
First thing first. I had an error in my config.

The line

```
if (!-d /home/sites/dev/ilundev.no/public/$1) {
```

was wrong, and should be

```
if (!-d /home/sites/dev/$1) {
```

And, I had to set up a wildcard entry to my domain, at my domain provider. 
The entry looked like "*.ilundev.no" and I used the "A" option - and it worked!

---

Updated and optimized config:

This will work as long as the DNS at your domain provider properly sets "*.dev" in a subdomain for your domain, with the "A" option - and the IP of your server.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.ilun.no www.dev.ilun.no;
    root /home/sites/dev;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name   ~^(.*)\.dev.ilun\.no$;
    if (!-d /home/sites/dev/$1) {
        rewrite . http://dev.ilun.no/ redirect;
    }
    root /home/sites/dev/$1;
}
```

---

However, now I'm stuck trying to make the server run php code in such a subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<branch>.*)\.example\.com;
    root /var/www/$branch/public;   

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/$branch.example.com.error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Noticed one issue - variables are not allowed inside error_log, so branch won't be replaced with actual value :)